# Python multiprocess threading errors out or exits code when calling pool.join

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

The threading seems to be working, and I'm able to print to the console some checks to validate that it's running, but when it hits `pool.join()` it stalls for a few seconds and either gives me this error:

`in poll pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag) KeyboardInterrupt`

or it just ends the process with and exit code of 0. I've got an entire chunk of code that never gets touched as a result. Any idea what could be causing this to cycle between the error above and prematurely exiting the script?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with closing(Pool()) as pool:
       results =  pool.imap_unordered(reddit_search,
              ["wallstreetbets", "finance", "FinancialIndependence", "Investing", "stocks", "pennystocks",
               "robinhoodpennystocks", "wallstreetbetsnew"])  
       pool.close()
       pool.join()


today = date.today()
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=post_dict, orient='index')
     .to_csv('./data/tick_Post_' + str(today) + 'Thread.csv', header=False))
```

The code starting with `today = date.today()` never gets touched.

Comment: what's the `closing()` for?

Comment: why not just `with Pool() as pool: pool.imap_unordered(reddit_search,["wallstreetbets", "finance", "FinancialIndependence", "Investing", "stocks", "pennystocks",  "robinhoodpennystocks", "wallstreetbetsnew"])`

Comment: @mirhossein when I try without the `closing()` it errors out saying the pool is still running. This is my first time using threading so I'm not as familiar with best practices

Comment: Could u try the code in the previous comment?

Comment: @mirhossein the above code resulted in the code finishing without errors, but also not entering the `reddit_search` function. I'm judging this based on the print statements within the function that should be getting executed, but are not.

Comment: It's my mistake. use `pool.map(...)` or `list(pool.imap_unordered(...))`

Comment: @mirhossein the last suggestion resulted in a error: `poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: Could you show the complete code? I'd want to run it locally